# MongoDB point in time recovery

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

I'm attempting to perform a Point in Time oplog restore and the system tells me my oplog on the running system is newer than the oplog I'm attempting to restore from and bails out.

I'm using mongo 2.4

```
mongorestore --port 27017  --oplogReplay   --oplogLimit="<1389734460:1>"
```

Comment: what version of mongod executed the mongodump?

Comment: There's not enough information to offer any meaningful help here. A single error message without the context like how the backups were made, where the oplog was captured from, and so on, does not allow for an answer.